# Cannot share screen with TV through HDMI

Tags: hdmi, display-settings

I am unable to share screen with my LG TV on ubuntu 20.04. I have installed vino for sharing screen via hdmi. When I connect my LG TV with my laptop, the screen is not shared but my TV is visible in the "Displays" section in the settings. Here is the screenshot. I tried everything from setting primary display to single display but nothing worked.
[image]

Comment: The screenshot is now showing the properties of the Built-in display. Could you please replace that with one that shows the properties of the TV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before trying on ubuntu, I tried to connect a Macbook pro with a Sony TV, but that also resulted in this same problem. I was just about to give up my ubuntu system and was unplugging the wire and then the display was mirrored on my LG TV, so I thought there might be some issue with the hdmi cable. After some time I tried the same thing on Macbook pro - Sony TV and it worked(just adjusted the wire), strange.